# Datasnap. Как "заставить" систему не создавать unit1 клиентских модулей

Tags: delphi

в Delphi 10.2 создал DataSnapClient Application и автоматически создался модуль ClienClassesUnit1 в котором есть только тестовые методы(echostring, reversestring). Соответсвенно в свойстве servermethodname компонента sqlservermethod не могу выбирать мой методы. А когда в контекстном меню компонента SqlConnection выбираю 'generate datasnap client classes' снова создаётся unit1 где есть мой методы.
Как "заставить" систему использовать и добавить новые методы в ClienClassesUnit1?

**UPDATE**: переименовал в ClienClassesUnit1 и перезаписал один раз и потом уже находит ClienClassesUnit1.

Comment: Оформите в виде ответа. Не успел отписать что нужно сохранить сгенерированный файл и дальше генерация будет проходить "в него".